# follow unfollow feed with observer pattern android app

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, reactive

I am building an android app which has follow and unfollow feature. I have 3 pages inside `ViewPager` in main home. Feed consist of post of the users based on interest.

For example, user A follows user B, that posts the article in 3 different interest food, travel and tech. In this case, user A will be able to see his all the post in the 3 different places. What I want is that if user A who follows B unfollow the user B from any of the page it will just get removed from all the pages and refresh the feed.

I want to observe that follow and unfollow event based on the user action and refresh the feed.

How to build observer for this pattern. I am open to use anything expect `BroadcastReceiver`.

**feed_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                    android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                   fresco:roundedCornerRadius="@dimen/feed_rect_card_radius" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkTextColor" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/data"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/noto_sans_bold"
                        android:textColor="#747474"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/followBtn"
           style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/noto_sans_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/follow"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:rippleColor="@color/green"
            app:strokeColor="@color/green" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pop_up_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|top"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_more_dark" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp">

                <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="124dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    fresco:roundedCornerRadius="@dimen/feed_rect_card_radius" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_feature" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/item_offset">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/post_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/noto_sans_bold"
                        android:gravity="start|top"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkTextColor"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/post_desc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/noto_sans"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/categoryLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/whatsAppShare"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:padding="4dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_whatsapp_fill" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**FeedAdapter**

```
class FeedAdapter(private val mContext: Context, val fg: FragmentManager, val nodes: ArrayList<Feed.Item>, val tagId: Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    var showLoader: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            ViewTypes.FEED -> FeedItemVH(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false))
            else -> FooterViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_footer, parent, false))
        }
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is FeedItemVH -> feedItemView(holder, nodes[position].fragments().feedItem())
            else -> {
                if (showLoader) (holder as FooterViewHolder).itemView.footerLoader.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                else (holder as FooterViewHolder).itemView.footerLoader.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }

    private fun feedItemView(holder: FeedItemVH, feed: FeedItem) {

        holder.followBtn.setOnClickListener { 
        //API call to follow/unfollow user and broadcast the result. 
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return when (nodes.size) {
            0 -> 0
            else -> nodes.size + 1
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when {
            position != 0 && position == itemCount - 1 -> ViewTypes.LOADER
            else -> {
                ViewTypes.FEED
            }
        }
    }


    fun showLoader(status: Boolean) {
        showLoader = status
        Handler().post { this.notifyDataSetChanged() }
    }


    interface ViewTypes {
        companion object {
            const val FEED = 1
            const val LOADER = 2
        }
    }
}
```

Any type of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: your question (as it currently stands) is too broad. you should consider posting some existing code and narrow your question to be more specific

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have recycler view with feed fragment. On click of the follow button i call the apis to follow unfollow the user. Do you want me to post that?

Comment: yes :) you should post any relevant code to your issue, then people will be more than willing to help you

Comment: @a_local_nobody is there any way to solve this by RxJava ?

Comment: post your existing code and explain what you're struggling with related to that code and you will get help

Comment: @a_local_nobody please check now.